# How do I run a program in a Windows batch file without waiting for the program to exit? I can't get current SO answers to work

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that opens Visual Studio Code.  I'm using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848306/2023861) as a guide to do so.  This is the command I end up with:

```
start "MyTitle" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" "C:\MyFolder"
```

When I run this, I see two command windows appear:

- One window runs the command and closes immediately.  I think this is right.
- The other window is titled "MyTitle" and gives me this error message:

  - *'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.*

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to escape the spaces in that path?

I've found a lot of SO questions relating to this, and I've tried the solutions I've found, but I can't get anything to work.  Here are some answers I've found and tried:

- [Opening/Closing application via .bat file [Windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027461/opening-closing-application-via-bat-file-windows)
- [Run a Program and exit the cmd window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570150/run-a-program-and-exit-the-cmd-window)
- [Windows batch file, wait for command to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40193625/windows-batch-file-wait-for-command-to-finish)
- [How can I run a program from a batch file without leaving the console open after the program starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324539/how-can-i-run-a-program-from-a-batch-file-without-leaving-the-console-open-after)

Comment: Have you addressed the space issue first? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537098/spaces-cause-split-in-path-with-powershell

Comment: The batch file `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"` will spawn the .exe `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"` anyway and terminate, so simply **call** the batch to have it return to the batch afterwards.

Comment: @wannadream I'm not using Powershell.  If I can't get this batch script figured out, I'll switch to Powershell.

Comment: @LotPings That fixed it.  I dind't think to look into the *.cmd file.  Now my command is `start "MyTitle" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "C:\MyFolder"`